# javascript forEach - remove iterations containing class and add class to next iteration

Tags: javascript, foreach

So I'm trying to make a multi-step form with the active class applied to the current step. Upon clicking next I want to remove that class and add it to the next iteration of those classes.

```js
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.next');
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.previous');
const submitBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.submit');
const progress_li = document.querySelector('.progress-bar_li');
const fieldset = document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
const step = document.getElementsByClassName(
  'step'
);
const active_fieldset = document.getElementsByClassName('activeFieldset');

[...nextBtn].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    [...registration_fieldset].forEach((className, i) => {
      if (className.classList.contains('activeFieldset')) {
        className.classList.remove('activeFieldset');
        step[i + 1].classList.add('activeFieldset');
        //^this doesn't work, nor does subbing step with className
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
Pug
mixin nextandprev
    .btn-small.btn-small__reg.next Next
    .btn-small.btn-small__reg.previous Previous
    
mixin next
    .btn-small.btn-small__reg.next Next

mixin prevandsubmit
    .btn-small.btn-small__reg.previous Previous
    .btn-small.btn-small__reg.submit Submit

<fieldset class="step activeFieldset">part 1
   +next
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step">sub 1 part 2
  nextandprev
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step"> sub 2 part 2
  nextandprev
  </fieldset>
 </fieldset>
<fieldset class="step">part 3
nextandprev
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="step">part 4
nextandprev
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="step">part 5
nextandprev
</fieldset>
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.  I want to get way better at understanding these forEach loops

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the same number of next buttons and steps, you could use the button index with the step index to add the class onto the next step and remove from all the other steps.

```js
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.next');
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.previous');
const steps = document.querySelectorAll('.step');

nextBtn.forEach((btn, btnIndex) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    steps.forEach((step, stepIndex) => {
      // If button is for next step, add class to next step, else remove
      if (btnIndex === stepIndex - 1) {
        step.classList.add('activeFieldset');
      } else {
        step.classList.remove('activeFieldset');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.activeFieldset {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="step activeFieldset">
      <div>Part 1</div>
      <button class="next">Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <fieldset class="step">
        <div>Sub 1 Part 2</div>
        <button class="previous">Prev</button>
        <button class="next">Next</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="step">
        <div>Sub 2 Part 2</div>
        <button class="previous">Prev</button>
        <button class="next">Next</button>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step">
      <div>Part 3</div>
      <button class="previous">Prev</button>
      <button class="next">Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step">
      <div>Part 4</div>
      <button class="previous">Prev</button>
      <button class="next">Next</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step">
      <div>Part 5</div>
      <button class="previous">Prev</button>
      <button class="next">Next</button>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you that works!  I appreciate your help.